# Ошибка в сортировке строки

Tags: c++, строки, сортировка

я пытался сделать сортировку слов в строке по алфавиту но к сожаления не вышло ,подскажите что я не так делаю ?Прошу прошения если вопрос оформлен не корректно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
 
using namespace std;
 
void sortWord(char string[]);
 
int main()
{
    char str[256];
    string words[256];
    int start, end;
    int WordCounter = 0;
    size_t words_sz = 0;
    
    cout<<"Enter str:";
    gets(str);
    
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0')
        {
            while(str[i] == ' ') i++;
            start = i;
            while(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0') i++;
            while(str[i] == ' ') i++;
            end = i;
            words[words_sz++] = string(start, end);
        }
    }
    string tmp;
    for(int j=0;j<words_sz;j++)
    {
        if(words[j]<words[j+1])
        {
        tmp=words[j];
        words[j]=words[j+1];
        words[j+1]=tmp;
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"Line view after sort words:";
    //puts(str);
    
    for(int j=0;j<words_sz;j++)
    {
        cout<<words[j];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Тест]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть 2 проблемы:

1. Проблема в том, что у вас массив `words` заполняется не правильно. Лучше когда парсите строку, работать с указателями.
   И зачем внутри цикла проверка `if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\0')`?

   Вот пример рабочего кода:

   ```
   char* s = str;
   char *start, *end;
   while(*s != '\0')
   {
       while (*s != '\0' && *s == ' ') ++s;
       start = s;
       while (*s != '\0' && *s != ' ') ++s;
       while (*s != '\0' && *s == ' ') ++s;
       end = s;
       words[words_sz++] = string(start, end);
   }
   ```
2. Я думаю после того, как вы спарсили слова в массив `words` вы сортируете их алгоритмом пузырьком. Тогда у вас не правильно написан алгоритм:

   Вот пример рабочего кода:

   ```
   string tmp;
   for (int i = 0; i < words_sz - 1; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < words_sz - i - 1; j++) {
           if (words[j] > words[j + 1]) {
               tmp = words[j];
               words[j] = words[j + 1];
               words[j + 1] = tmp;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Да, действительно , все заработало .Спасибо вам огромное .